# how to loop python code

Tags: python

I made the beginning of a basic text adventure game, and I want it to loop whenever you die, but any examples of code I see aren't working, and thorugh research i still cant find something that could work.

```
print("A tale of time version 0.0.1. by Tylan Merriam")
print("you awaken, the room is dark and you cannot see. the sheets on your 
bed are damp, and you hear a faint dripping sound.")
ch0pg1 = input('>: ')
if ch0pg1 == 'turn on light':
    print("you flip the light on, it turns out the dripping was from a leaky 
pipe above you. you see a dresser(outisde of bed) a chair with something 
glinting on it(outside of bed) and a window(outisde of bed)")
ch1p1 = input('>: ')
    if ch1p1 == 'stand':    
        print('you stand up, the game isnt finished so this is all there is, 
try saying stand at the first choice or anything else')
    else:
        print('sorry, but i have no fricking clue what that means')
elif ch0pg1 == 'stand':
    print('since you cannot see, you bump your head on a brick and collapse. 
as you think of your last words you realize the only thing that comes to 
mind is wushtub.')
    diemessage = input('>: ')
    if diemessage == 'lol':
        print('i agree, now shut up, your dead')
    else:
        print('shut it, your dead')
else:
   print('I have no clue what that means,')
```

Comment: The way you code the game is quite messy, it will get more complicated when you code more, I suggest you using object-oriented programming while programming a quality project.

Answer (score 1):

You can try embedding a while loop within a while loop kind of like this.

```
while(1):
    while(1):
         # some code
             # also some code
             diemessage = input('>: ')
             if diemessage == 'lol':
                print('i agree, now shut up, your dead')
                chc = input("play again? (y,n): ")
                if chc == "y":
                    break # break this while loop which just starts again
                elif chc == "n":
                    exit() # exit the game entirely
                else:
                    # You can set this bit to your liking.
                    print("thats no answer, bye")
                    exit()
             else:
                print('shut it, your dead')
                chc = input("play again? (y,n): ")
                if chc == "y":
                    break # break this while loop which just starts again
                elif chc == "n":
                    exit() # exit the game entirely
                else:
                    # You can set this bit to your liking.
                    print("thats no answer, bye")
                    exit()
```

It simply creates a while loop for the game inside of a while loop. Break breaks out of the while loop while being ran, so it just exits and starts again. If the user chooses to quit, it stops the whole program.

You would think that we could create a function to make it easier, but when I tried breaking with a function it won't break, so you are going to have to keep pasting this in as of what I know. :P

Answer (score -1):

Could do:

```
while (true)
{
//print statements

//whenever you die:
continue;

}
```

Comment: The continue would have to be in an if statement. E.g. if ( input == "I will die") {  continue; }

Answer (score -3):

Well, you first need to define what you want to loop. Make a function called game() with your included code. Then this would work:

```
if diemessage == "lol":
  print("something")
else:
  print("Shut it, your dead")
  game()
```

Comment: Ahah, im hungover and tired af. So i couldnt get the stackoverflow code thing to work so it looked messy af. Sorry bout that